# What could go wrong if I don't use * in my \hyperref command?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, links

The Latex manual on wikibooks says that you should use the `\hyperref` command as follows:

```
We use \hyperref[mainlemma]{lemma \ref*{mainlemma} }.
```

Where "mainlemma" is the labelname. It then says:

> Note the `*`  after `\ref` for avoiding nested hyperlinks.

I've implemented this line in my document, once with and once without the `*` and I did not notice any difference.

So what could be the harm in not using the `*`?

Comment: I think using `autoref` is a much better and cleaner way. `We use \autoref{mainlemma}.`

Comment: I find the LaTeX manual on Wikibooks not completely trustworthy, in general. It's possible, though, that the implementation of `\hyperref` has changed to make `\ref` inside its argument to work like `\ref*`.

Comment: @Johannes_B `\autoref` does not work desirable in combination with a lemma defined by a `\newtheorem`-command...

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific on used packages and the *not desirable* part. Maybe post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You have to keep in mind, that you have to introduce your new theorem/lemma to hyperref. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{lma}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\lmaautorefname}{lemma}
\begin{document}
\begin{lma}
 a test\label{thm:test}
\end{lma}
see \autoref{thm:test}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried your suggestion, howerver it doesn't seem to work when the `lma`-environment uses the same counter as for instance the `thrm`-environment. As in `\newtheorem{lma}[thrm]{lemma}`. It then only produces the lemma's number and leaves the word "lemma" out.

Comment: Please try to be more verbose, i can't see your document.

Comment: The problem is the resulting nested hyperlinks caused if you don't use the starred version. There's no consistent behaviour for dealing with nested hyperlinks across all PDF viewers, so while the result may look okay to you in your PDF viewer it might behave differently for another user who wants to view your document.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot A very nice explanation. Might I suggest you post it as an answer...

Comment: @Johannes_B I'm sorry for not providing an MWE, but I feel that an elaboration on how `\autoref` is properly used digresses too much from my original question and is better off being a seperate  question. The effort is much appreciated though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key issue is that without using the starred version, the document ends up with a nested hyperlink. Since PDF viewers don't have a consistent way of dealing with nested hyperlinks this can lead to unexpected results.

To illustrate this, consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}
\label{sample}

\section{Another Sample}

\hyperref[sample]{section~\ref{sample}}

\end{document}
```

In `okular` this is displayed as:

[image: Both hyperlinks boxed]

The use of `hidelinks` or `colorlinks` can appear to solve this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}
\label{sample}

\section{Another Sample}

\hyperref[sample]{section~\ref{sample}}

\end{document}
```

In `okular` this looks like:

[image: Links coloured red]

But if I change `okular`'s accessibility setting so that links are border it's then displayed as

[image: link text red both links boxed]

Since both the inner and outer links point to the same location, the actual hyperlinks in `okular` will send you to the same place, but it may confuse other PDF viewers. If the inner link points to a different location to the outer link, then there's even more confusion. This can happen when `\ref` is used in a sectioning command that ends up in the table of contents.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Sample}
\label{sample}

\section{Another Sample Following on from section \ref{sample}}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of document with table of contents]

Now the table of contents has a nested link but where that link takes you depends on the PDF viewer and whether you used the PDF or DVI format to generate your document. If I compile with `pdflatex` and then view the document with `okular` if I click on the inner link I get sent to section 2 but if I view the document in `evince` the inner link will send me to section 1. If I build the document using `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` the reverse happens.